# How can I make my quiz RANDOMLY select unseen Q's in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I have started to code a Multiple Choice Quiz, however I would like the Python program to randomly select an unseen question that the user has not already answered this should not include previously incorrectly answered questions. My current code is below:

---

**example.py**

```
print ('WELCOME TO THE MULTIPLE CHOICE TEST\n')
name = input('WHAT IS YOUR NAME? ')
print ('\nHI THERE ' + name + '! LET''S PLAY A GAME!\n')
print ('I will ask you 10 questions and give you three choices for each 
question.\n\nYou select which choice is the correct answer. Eg. A, B or 
C\n')
print ('\n-----------------------------------------------------------\n')

score = 0
score = int(score)  #Convert the 0 into a number so we can add scores

print ('Q1: What is 1 + 1\n')
print ('A. 1')
print ('B. 2')
print ('C. 0')
print ('')

Q1answer = "B"
Q1response= input('Your answer : ').upper()

if (Q1response != Q1answer):
    print ('Sorry, that is incorrect!')
else:
    print ('Well done! ' + Q1response + ' is correct!')
    score = score + 1

print ('Your current score is ' + str(score) + ' out of 10')
print ('\n-----------------------------------------------------------\n')

print ('Q2: What is 0 + 0')
print ('A. 0')
print ('B. 1')
print ('C. -1')
print ('')

Q2answer = "A" or "a"
Q2response= input('Your answer : ').upper()

if (Q2response != Q2answer):
    print ('Sorry, that is incorrect!')
else:
    print ('Well done! ' + Q2response + ' is correct!')
    score = score + 1

print ('Your current score is ' + str(score) + ' out of 10') 
print ('\n-----------------------------------------------------------\n')
```

**----------------------------------------------------------------------------**

REVISED CODE:

```
import random
score = 0
score = int(score)

questions = {  # (also contains the answers)
"What is 1 + 1?": "2",
"What is 0 + 0?": "0",
"What is 1 + 2?": "3",
"What is 1 + 3?": "4",
"What is 1 + 4?": "5",
"What is 2 + 1?": "3",
"What is 3 + 2?": "5",
"What is 8 + 2?": "10",
"What is 6 + 0?": "6",
"What is 6 + 1?": "7",
"What is 7 + 1?": "8",
"What is 10 + 0?": "0",
}
learned_questions = set()

while len(questions) > len(learned_questions):
    unanswered_questions = set(questions) - learned_questions
    chosen_question = random.choice(list(unanswered_questions))
    correct_answer = questions[chosen_question]

    print (chosen_question)
    given_answer = input()

    if given_answer == correct_answer:
        print ("Correct!")
        learned_questions.add(chosen_question)
        score = score + 1
        print ('Your current score is ' + str(score) + ' out of 10')
        print ('\n-----------------------------------------------------------\n')
    else:
        print ("Wrong!  Correct answer would have been:", correct_answer)
        print ('Your current score is ' + str(score) + ' out of 10')
        print ('\n-----------------------------------------------------------\n')
```

Comment: I advice you to put the question in an array and then you want a random one you just take array[random]

Comment: @Carlo1585 Hi, thank you for your reponse. I am new to Python, can you please show me how this is done?

Comment: Like Carlo said, keep them in an array or list or sthg similar. You might also create a Question class, so you can save entire questions + answers in a single object. Add a "get_answers" and a "check_answer" method can even help you randomize the answers sequence
You migt want to read this: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a collection of all existing questions:

```
questions = {  # (also contains the answers)
    "What is 1 + 1?": "2",
    "What is 0 + 0?": "0",
}
```

Make another collection of all correctly answered questions:

```
learned_questions = set()
```

Take only questions which are not part of the `learned_questions` by making a choice from the difference of two sets:

```
unanswered_questions = set(questions) - learned_questions
chosen_question = random.choice(list(unanswered_questions))
correct_answer = questions[chosen_question]
```

Ask the user for his answer:

```
print chosen_question
given_answer = raw_input()
```

Check the given answer and if it is correct, add this question to the collection of learned questions:

```
if given_answer == correct_answer:
  print "Correct!"
  learned_questions.add(chosen_question)
else:
  print "Wrong!  Correct answer would have been:", correct_answer
```

And do all of this in a loop until all questions are learned:

```
while len(questions) > len(learned_questions):
    …
```

All together now:

```
questions = {  # (also contains the answers)
    "What is 1 + 1?": "2",
    "What is 0 + 0?": "0",
}
learned_questions = set()
while len(questions) > len(learned_questions):
  unanswered_questions = set(questions) - learned_questions
  chosen_question = random.choice(list(unanswered_questions))
  correct_answer = questions[chosen_question]
  print chosen_question
  given_answer = raw_input()
  if given_answer == correct_answer:
    print "Correct!"
    learned_questions.add(chosen_question)
  else:
    print "Wrong!  Correct answer would have been:", correct_answer
```

Comment: `random.choice` raises an `IndexError` when used on a set.

Comment: @alfe I receive an index error when implementing the above.